# Generating a precache manifest for service workers

Tags: cache, routes

I'm thinking of using [Google's Workbox to pre-cache a bunch of files](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/), and I've been scratching my head as to how to generate unique hashes for files when they change. Something like this:

```
 workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
    { 
      url: '/',
      revision: '383676',
    },
    { 
      url: '/about',
      revision: 213142,
    },
    { 
      town: '/location',
      revision: 742125,
    },
  ]);
```

Ideally the revision number would change when the entry or related entries included in the page are changed/saved. I got this working but I'm not sure how to get related content to clear the cache:

```
// service-worker.js

{%- cache using key 'abc' -%}
    { 
      url: {{ craft.entries.id(64).one.uri }},
      revision: {{ random(100000, 999999) }},
    },
{%- endcache -%}
```

This seems to work when said entry is saved, but I'm not sure how to deal with a related entry being saved. I'm also not sure this is the most performant way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you shouldn't try to come up with a hashed file naming scheme for busting the cache; instead use one of Workbox's [Strategies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies) -- I think a great pattern for what you're trying to do is [Stale While Revalidate](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#stale-while-revalidate)

TL;DR Workbox has strategies for doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but this is what I'm wondering: does re-validating mean going back to the server and requesting the page (and querying the DB) even if the page hasn't changed? I'd imagine that with a manifest, if the hashed file hasn't changed, then the SW would simply serve from the cache and stay away from the server until instructed to do so.

Comment: There are many strategies you can adopt... my point is really that Workbox can handle this for you, you're not going to need template logic.

Comment: It took me a while to wrap my head around all this, but the precache manifest is useful primarily for static assets (js, css...). In my case, stale-while-revalidate is probably the way to go for content, provided I can workout how to refresh the page when new content is available.